# Handling Exception using C# Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I was thinking that is it possible to do exception handling using Attribute, rather than write "try...catch" in every single method.

for example, now, each of my method look like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // exception handling rules, always the same.
        throw;
    }
}
```

I want:

```
[HandleException]
public void DoSomething()
{
    // do something
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done via AOP (aspect oriented programming).
One of the frameworks for doing so is PostSharp.
See a sample http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/exception

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can write your own MSBuild Task.
[Here you can](http://kindofmagic.codeplex.com/) find an opensource project. During compile time it injects `INotifyPropertyChanged` supporting code in property setters  using `Mono.Cecil` lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Fody

https://github.com/Fody/Fody

There is a similar plugin to handle exceptions on async code if you want to check it.

https://github.com/Fody/AsyncErrorHandler

And here is one tutorial.

https://michielsioen.be/2017-10-21-il-weaving/

https://michielsioen.be/2017-12-28-il-weaving-pt2/